# Google Drive API Python Client: How to retrieve list of created folder IDs when created in batch?

Tags: python, batch-processing, google-api-python-client

Following code works to create a set of folders using batch request.

```py
from google.oauth2 import service_account
from googleapiclient import discovery, http

credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file('/home/user/Documents/code/credentials.json')
scoped_credentials = credentials.with_scopes(['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'])
drive = discovery.build('drive', 'v3', credentials=scoped_credentials)

names = ['test1', 'test2', 'test3']
batch = drive.new_batch_http_request()

for name in names:
    folder_metadata = {'name': name,
                       'mimeType': 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'}
    batch.add(drive.files().create(body=folder_metadata, fields='id'))
res = batch.execute()
```

However, I would like to retrieve the list of tuples (folder_name_, folder_id).
`res` object returned is `None`.

Any ideas?

### Edit

Here is an updated code, but `res` remains `None`.

```py
names = ['test1', 'test2', 'test3']

def receive_callback(request_id, response, exception):
    #response should have the details about folders
    return response['id'], response['name']

# batch = drive.new_batch_http_request()
batch = drive.new_batch_http_request(receive_callback)

for name in names:
    folder_metadata = {'name': name,
                       'mimeType': 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'}
    batch.add(drive.files().create(body=folder_metadata, fields='id, name'))
res = batch.execute()
```

Thanks for any help.
Bests,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def receive_callback(request_id, response, exception):
    #response should have the details about folders
```

replace

```
batch = drive.new_batch_http_request()
```

with

```
batch = drive.new_batch_http_request(receive_callback)
```

You will receive the response of each request of the folder creation request that you made

Comment: Hi, thanks for tying to help. Please, can you be a bit more explicit? How do you retrieve the response? I updated the code I tried, and res is still `None`. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You will receive the receive the response inside the recieve callback function

Comment: Yes, this is what my code is showing. But when returning the response, `res` remains `None`.

Comment: Res will always be none as execute doesn't return anything . You need to do the processing in callback function itself.  you can create an empty list outside function and append the response to it inside callback function